# Amazon S3 - iPhone won't play private mp3

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3, jplayer

I'm using [JPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) to play mp3 files which are located on my Amazon S3 server.

This plays nicely on both web browsers and iPhone.

However, when I set the media to private and add a bucket policy to allow access for my domain, the iPhone browser can no longer find the mp3 file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that Safari will not play mp3s from a private bucket.  Instead I've made the bucket public and generating expiring links for jPlayer to use